# Excel VBA Userform Dynamic Treeview

Tags: excel, vba, treeview

I'm a reasonably decent excel vba programmer and I want to create a dynamic treeview where the user can create elements/tiers in a very user friendly way.

I'm looking for direction on if it would be possible to create a drag & drop, snap-to-point visual treeview in a userform.

Could anyone provide some direction on what would be a feasible path?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure it is easy to cover that kind of broad question in a single answer. You can utilize existing TreeView control (part of MSCOMCTL), program something from scratch or use other existing projects. I think there is at least one for TreeView specifically. Building upon existing TreeView is possible, but MSCOMCTL can be a pain - for me it always leads to issues on updates such as file corruption and file crashes.

Comment: A main caveat seems to be that standard Treeview control, like all non built-in ActiveX controls, cannot be used in 64 bit versions of Office. - A nice open source for a workaround can be found at [JKP MSForms (all VBA) treeview Excel/Word/Access ](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp).